# Poisson distribution on pizza request

Tags: poisson-distribution

The demand of IT service is a random variable ($X$) having the Poisson distribution $μ=3.4$. The cost of producing each pizza is $\$20$ and each is sold at a selling price of $\$40$. Suppose $5$ pizza are made daily, no pizza is reserved for next day. Find the expected total profit daily.

$$p(0) \times (-100) + p(1) \times (-60) + p(2) \times (-20) + p(3) \times 20 + p(4) \times 40 + p(\ge 5) \times 100$$

My answer = $27.1004$. Suggest ans $= 27.118$.

Do I miss anything ?

Thx

Comment: A pizza that sells for 40 bucks?!  They'll hardly sell a piece at all.